# Formula to get the dates of all Sundays in the year

Tags: apple-numbers

I am trying to create a spreadsheet with all the dates of Sunday in one column. How can I go about doing this? I have tried by using `DAYVALUE(1)`, but cant get that to return a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, e.g. in Calendar, lookup the *date* of the *first Sunday* in *January* for the *year* you want to create the spreadsheet of Sundays in a year. For this example, lets use the *first Sunday* in *January* of *2017*, i.e. January 1, 2017.

In **Numbers**, e.g.:

- Set `A1` to: `Date`
- Set `A2` to: `January 1, 2017`
- Set `A3` to: `=A2+7`
- Drag `A3` down to: `A54`

[image: Numbers Spreadsheet]